# How to add key to array and transform to object?

Tags: underscore.js

I have example data like,

```
var data = ['admin', 'designer', 'marketing'];
```

I want to change them in to object with keys 'value', 'text'.

Like this.

```
[{'value':'admin', 'text':'admin'},
{'value':'designer', 'text':'designer'},
{'value':'marketing', 'text':'marketing'}]
```

How should I do ?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the `_.map` function. You want to map each element in your array into an object with the two properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `map` function as @torazaburo said:

```
['admin', 'designer', 'marketing'].map(function(item) { 
    return { 
        value: item, 
        text: item 
    } 
})
```